# Draw a 3D MKPolyline in iOS 6

Tags: ios, mapkit

Is there a way to draw a 3D MKPolyline in iOS 6 with their new maps? (for example, aircraft landing track)

Comment: Offhand I would say no.  MKPolyline and it's super-classes use either `CLLocationCoordinate2D *` or `MKMapPoint *` data types, both of which are 2D. But this is a great question - I'd like to know if this is possible as well.